Play Axis resets the visual Scroller when it makes a page break
I have a report in which I have a table that I paginate with the visual play axis and on the other hand I have a visual scroller in which I show a list of countries
This report goes automatically on a screen and I have the play axis with the loop and auto start activated so that the pagination of the page goes automatically.

The problem is that every time play axis makes a page break the scroller restarts and starts again
I have made sure that the play axis does not interact with the visual scroller but the error still persists.
Why does this happen with these two visuals?
Could it be that these visuals share the same timer internally?
Thanks,
